# Dynamic Programming for coin change

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, computer-science

A given amount x should be changed in a coin system C = {c1, c2, … ck} such that each coin ci has a given weight wi. We would like to calculate the total weight of the possible changes. Two changes are different if they contain the same coins in different order.

How can we give a dynamic programming recursion for the above problem? I know the recursion for minimum coin change problem (i.e. C(x)=min{C(x-c)+1 for x>0}). But my confusion is the total weight of the possible changes.Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear, how are weights taken into consideration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like naive approach "store answer in the array" works. Let's C[i] represents coin value and W[i] represents coin weight, N is number of coins.

Recursion part looks like this:

```
long sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    if (C[i] <= x)
        sum += W[i] + total_change_weight(x-C[i]);
```

sample program without input, output and C/W initialization follows:

```
#define N   10
#define MAX_VALUE   101

long C[N];
long W[N];
long totals[MAX_VALUE];

long total_change_weight(long x) 
{
    if (x == 0) 
        return 0;
    if (totals[x] >= 0)
        return totals[x];

    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        if (C[i] <= x)
            sum += W[i] + total_change_weight(x-C[i]);
    totals[x] = sum;

    return sum;
}

void main () 
{
    long value = 100;
    //initialize C
    ...
    //initialize W
    ...
    //initialize totals
    for (long i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE; ++i)
        totals[i] = -1;
    long result = total_change_weight(value);
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between coin value and weight? Thanks.

Comment: value is, say, $1; weight is, say, 3 gramm

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. But how can we write the recursion with out Pseudo code?

Comment: Actually, essential part was in C++ code. I've updated answer with more or less complete calculation part. In real application you need to make arrays C, N, totals available inside function, initialize them through new, check borders for totals etc.

Comment: Than you. But I have still doubt. My question was to find recursion instead of the program code (if I am not mistaken)

Comment: Recursion condition is like that: C(x)=sum{C(x-ci)+wi for x>0 and ci>=x}, but it misses some border cases. Unfortunately it's easier to express all conditions in imperative programming way rather than make weird recursion condition.